# How could you group/ungroup data in an HTML page like you can in Excel?

Tags: html

Is it possible to group/ungroup data in a static HTML page, like you can in Excel?

I have a requirement to allow grouping/ungrouping of data like in Excel.

If it is not possible in a static HTML page, kindly suggest to me the best way to do it in order to get the same result in an HTML page.

Comment: What exactly do you mean?  Can you provide an example and a sample of the data?  Also, don't forget to mark correct answers to your previous questions.

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery ( or a JS framework of your choice ) to filter/group client side or if your getting the data from a database ( such as MySQL ) you can group the data from the query before rendering it to the client.

have a look at

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/GroupRows

Comment: But here the values will be generated from Access macros and not from the single data source or query from other database. Lets say the values are coming at run time while processing from a macro.

Comment: The macro is returning HTML? if yes, and if the html table is designed correctly you can still apply jquery table plugins after the page is completely loaded.

Comment: I have to publish the "n" number of HTML files which contain this group/ungroup data. There are number of users will be viewing the files. In order to view this jquery plugins should be installed in the clients' system?